# Change Color of Splash Screen Spinner in cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

I'm about to finish my first App with Ionic/Cordova.

YES it's GREAT, but sometimes I wonder why things are so complicated (with all those plugins and stuff :) )

I wonder if I can change the ***color of my Splash-Screen-Spinner***.

Any Ideas? I search in die Source-Code: Color, Spinner....., but i didn't find a hint.

I think this would help so many people.

Greetings

Comment: For android, you may find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026019/cordova-splash-screen-change-spinner-color-on-android

Answer (score 4):

At least with Cordova 7.0 and Cordova iOS 4.4.0, there's no need to change the splash screen plugin's source code. You can just add the following line to your `config.xml` file and the spinner will appear as white instead of grey.

```
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="whiteLarge" />
```

**NOTE**: The Apache Cordova documentation is a bit confusing when it comes to the spinner. The [config.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html) guide says the following about `TopActivityIndicator`:

> Controls the appearance of the small spinning icon in the status bar that indicates significant processor activity.

I believe that statement refers to the following spinner:

[image]

However, at least on iOS as of Cordova 7.0, changing `TopActivityIndicator` affects the appearance of the spinner that appears in the middle of the screen while the app is opening. Here's an example of the `whiteLarge` setting:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" Spinner colour on iOS. There are 3 predefined colour options to choose from (no idea how to change it to any colour). You have to manually edit the iOS plugin file "CDVSplashScreen.m" found inside "/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/ios".

**gray (default - search for this line):**

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle topActivityIndicatorStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray
```

**white**

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle topActivityIndicatorStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
```

**whiteLarge**

```
UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle topActivityIndicatorStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge
```

**Found in the files:**

```
/*
 * The Activity View is the top spinning throbber in the status/battery bar. We init it with the default Grey Style.
 *
 *     whiteLarge = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge
 *     white      = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite
 *     gray       = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray
 *
 */
```

I also found a way to change the spinner position check out my [stack post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735000/cordova-splash-screen-change-the-position-of-the-spinner/36736364#36736364)

Comment: Changing this line didn't work for me. The spinner is still gray.  Does it work for someone ?

Comment: @Clemorphy definitely working. Busy using this code ATM with no issues.

Comment: did you only change line 84 of this file ? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/src/ios/CDVSplashScreen.m   Because that does not change anything for me ...

Comment: @Clemorphy yes (and other stuff in my configuration). but are you sure you are loading in the plugin correctly?

Answer (score 0):

> `SplashScreenSpinnerColor` (string, defaults to system accent color):
>   hash, rgb notation or CSS color name.

In your `config.xml`, you can add the following preferences:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="white" />
```

You can also change `SplashScreenBackgroundColor`:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value="0xFFFFFFFF"/>
```

Refer [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/#preferences) link for further.